# Assigning a list of labels values generated from a list of objects

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, loops, foreach

I have an ajax call that returns a Serialized JSON string with various keys and values within it, I want to loop through these values and assign each individual key and value to a different label, I already have 8 labels set up. (I am quite new to Javascript so any help or constructive feedback would be greatly appreciated)

Haven't tried much as I am quite new to JavaScript

```
var obj = response.ret.SearchCriteria;

var resultJSON = obj;

var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);

var count = Object.keys(result).length;

for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {

  var c = $('#lbl' + [i]);

  $.each(result, function(k, v) {

    c.text(k + ' is ' + v);

  });

};
```

I have 6 labels and the last item of the JSON array (String) is displayed in each label

Comment: as described it seems a job for map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map, could you share an example of the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is why only last item of JSON array is being displayed in each label.

This is because of `c.text(k + ' is ' + v)`.
Here the existing text content is replaced with every iteration of 'each' loop
Instead, you can consider doing this, which will append existing content as well with `$.each` loop.

```
c.text(c.text() + k + ' is ' + v)
```

OR
Simply

```
c.append( k + ' is ' + v)
```

If I am wrong in my assumption, please describe your scenario more, so that we can help you out :)